# Cambiar datos columna de dataframe usando regex

Tags: python, regex, pandas, dataframe

tengo una columna de fechas con un montón de datos de forma distinta. Para limpiar estoy usando regex, quiero dejar solo los datos día, mes y año. Utilizo este código pero no está funcionando;

```
df1['Date1']=[]
for dat in df['Date']:
    res = re.findall(r"\d+\s\w+\s\d+",dat)
    if res:
        df1['Date1'].append(res[0])
    else:
       df1['Date1'].append('')
df1['Date1']
```

Comment: Hola. ¿Has podido solucionar con la respuesta proporcionada? Saludos

Answer (score 2, accepted):

L.Bar5522:

La expresión regular va a depender del formato que necesites, e.g:

- 31-12-1999

```
((\d{4})\-(0[1-9]|1[012])\-(0[1-9]|[12]\d|3[01]))
```

- 1999/12/31

```
((\d{4})\/(0[1-9]|1[012])\/(0[1-9]|[12]\d|3[01]))
```

Con estos dos ejemplos, podrías jugar un poco con el formato requerido.

Ahora, podemos aplicar la expresión regular con un dataframe de ejemplo:

```
import pandas as pd
import re

df = pd.DataFrame(pd.date_range(start='1-1-2020', end ='1-6-2020', freq='12H'), columns=['date'])

print(df)
```

Donde el resultado sería el siguiente:

```
                  date
0  2020-01-01 00:00:00
1  2020-01-01 12:00:00
2  2020-01-02 00:00:00
3  2020-01-02 12:00:00
4  2020-01-03 00:00:00
5  2020-01-03 12:00:00
6  2020-01-04 00:00:00
7  2020-01-04 12:00:00
8  2020-01-05 00:00:00
9  2020-01-05 12:00:00
10 2020-01-06 00:00:00
```

Podrías utilizar, por ejemplo, extract combinado con la expresión regular para sacar la porción que necesites de la serie del dataframe:

```
expresion_regular = "((\d{4})\-(0[1-9]|1[012])\-(0[1-9]|[12]\d|3[01]))"
print(df['date'].astype(str).str.extract(pat = expresion_regular))
```

El resultado sería el siguiente:

```
             0     1   2   3
0   2020-01-01  2020  01  01
1   2020-01-01  2020  01  01
2   2020-01-02  2020  01  02
3   2020-01-02  2020  01  02
4   2020-01-03  2020  01  03
5   2020-01-03  2020  01  03
6   2020-01-04  2020  01  04
7   2020-01-04  2020  01  04
8   2020-01-05  2020  01  05
9   2020-01-05  2020  01  05
10  2020-01-06  2020  01  06
```

Espero haberte ayudado.